# Create Field With Default Value Of Different Field With No Data Loss

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a `datetime2` field that I need to be a `datetime` field.  If I try to run an `Alter Table` statement my SSMS session freezes and I have to force reboot with no change made, if I try to alter my design view of the table I get an error about needing to drop/re-create the table.

Which leads me to my question, if I have a field that is `datetime2` if I `Add Column helper1 datetime`  how could I set the default value of this column to `dt2` which is a `datetime2` data type?

Comment: What exact `ALTER TABLE` statement did you run and how big is the table (how many rows)?

Comment: roughly 400,000 rows and the alter table statement that I ran was Alter Table bluejacks
Alter Column d123 datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a computed column if you want to keep the column with datetime2 data.

```
 ALTER TABLE Your-Table 
 ADD helper1 AS 
       (
          CAST(Datetime2-Column AS datetime)
       );
```

If you want to completely change the column, you can add a new column, transfer the data, then drop the old column and re-name the new column to the name of the old column. Steps below:

```
 ALTER TABLE Your-Table ADD Datetime2-Column DATETIME2


 UPDATE Your-Table
 SET Datetime-Column = Datetime2-Column
 GO
```

Then drop datetime2 column.

```
ALTER TABLE Your-Table DROP COLUMN Datetime2-Column
```

Then re-name your datetime column to your original datetime2 column's name. You can do this in Management Studio or with sp_rename